# Reference request: semimarkov processes

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

What are some good modern introductions to the theory of semimarkov processes? To be clear, by a semimarkov processes, I mean a Markov chain, together with "waiting times" between transitions, the distributions of which may depend on the current state.

Comment: You may also want to consider material on Markov renewal processes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_renewal_process